# Proving $1+\cot^2(-\theta)=\csc^2(\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm stuck on this one proof that I just can't get for some reason. It seems really simple too, and I've tried just about everything I can think of, but I just keep going in circles.

> $$1+\cot^2(-\theta)=\csc^2(\theta)$$

I know that $1 + \cot^2(-\theta) = 1 - \cot^2(\theta)$; that is, that the function is odd, so $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

From there, I've tried a bunch of stuff - too much to list, but a few of them are (working with LHS):

1.) Replacing $\cot^2\theta$ by $\frac{1}{\tan^2(\theta)}$

2.) Replace $1$ by $\csc^2\theta - \cot^2\theta$

3.) Multiplying LHS by $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$ (Don't even remember why I tried this, I was just frustrated)

Could someone please point me in the right direction? This is driving me nuts.

Comment: just to be sure, are points 1.) and 2.) the correct replacements you want to do? $cot^{\theta}$ and $csc^{\theta}$?

Comment: Using the Pythagorean identity, divide both sides by $\sin^2{\theta}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to solve the problem by replacing $1$ by $\csc^2\theta - \cot^2\theta$ was a good idea.  Since $\cot\theta$ is an odd function, $\cot(-\theta) = -\cot\theta$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
1 + \cot^2(-\theta) & = 1 + (-\cot\theta)^2\\
                   & = 1 + \cot^2\theta\\
                   & = \csc^2\theta - \cot^2\theta + \cot^2\theta\\
                   & = \csc^2\theta
\end{align*}
Where you made your mistake was in concluding that the fact that cotangent is odd implied $1 + \cot^2(-\theta) = 1 - \cot^2\theta$ rather than $1 + \cot^2(-\theta) = 1 + (-\cot\theta)^2 = 1 + \cot^2\theta$.

Comment: Yes, I noticed my mistake as soon as I saw everyone's answers! Hit me like a ton of bricks, haha. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

$1+\cot^2(-\theta)=1+(-\cot\theta)^2=1+\cot^2\theta=1+\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\dfrac{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\dfrac{1}{\sin^2\theta}=\csc^2\theta$

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path:

$$\begin{align}1+\cot^2(\theta)
&=\frac{\sin^\color{green}2(\theta)}{\sin^\color{green}2(\theta)}(1+\cot^2(\theta))\\
&=\frac{\sin^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\cot^2(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}\\
&=\frac1{\sin^2(\theta)}\\
&=\csc^2(\theta).\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Initially note that 
$$\cot^2(-\theta)=(\cot(-\theta))^2=(-\cot\theta)^2=(\cot\theta)^2=\cot^2\theta$$
Then, proof the identity $1+\cot^2(-\theta)= \csc^2\theta$ is same that proof
$$1+\cot^2\theta=\csc^2\theta$$
Hence, divide the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ by $\sin^2\theta$.

$$\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}=\frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} \Rightarrow 1+\cot^2\theta=\csc^2\theta.$$

Comment: The commands for the trigonometric functions, used in math mode, are \sin for sine, \cos for cosine, \tan for tangent, \csc for cosecant, \sec for secant, and \cot for cotangent.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at these is to convert all expressions to ratios of the variables $o,a,h$
$$1+cot^2(-θ)=csc^2(θ)$$
$$1+(\frac{a}{o})^2=(\frac{h}{o})^2$$
$$(\frac{o}{o})^2+(\frac{a}{o})^2=(\frac{h}{o})^2$$
$$\frac{o^2+a^2}{o^2}=\frac{h^2}{o^2}$$
$$o^2+a^2=h^2$$

Which checks out due to the Pythagorean Theorem. I skipped over the negative angle identity of cotan since it is squared.